# Binomial Distribution Conditional?

Tags: self-study, binomial-distribution

I don't know how I'm getting this wrong.

Calculate P[ X > 7|X < 9 ]

So calculate P[X>7] given that X<9, I put X>7 as the numerator and X<9 as the denominator.

For X > 7, since the binomial distribution has .45920 I subtract that from 1, and use X <= 8 for X < 9, that value is .64437

(1 - .45920)/(.64437) = .839269

Wrong answer. The right answer is .28737

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: "*I put X>7 as the numerator*" -- there's your problem right there.

Comment: What should be the numerator?

Comment: Can you write down an expression for $P(A|B)$?

Comment: I guess it should be the union of X > 7 and X < 9, but I have no idea how to do that from the binomial distribution table.

Comment: What values of x have P(X=x)>0 for which it is true that X>7 and X<9?

Comment: x = 8 or .64437, but I'm using that as denominator already.

Comment: x=8 is correct, but the probability you quote is not P(X=8), is it? It's something else. You shouldn't need a table for that, since you can compute it from the probability function easily (though you *can* get it by subtraction from the table).

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm really not getting it. I'm new at stats.

Comment: This is nothing to do with stats. The issue here is simple logic. I know you already know what probabilities are in your table, since you state it in your question. The first thing you must do is write down the quantities you need to compute. THEN worry about how to compute them. You know your numerator and denominator. Write yourself a simple question: "How do I compute P(X=8)?" and then think about it for more than a few seconds. I bet you already have the p.f., but in any case it's simple to compute it from the table -- you just can't look up P(X=8) in a table of cumulative probabilities.

Comment: Alright. I need to compute the union of X > 7 and X < 9, which could only be X > 8 = .64437. I also need the "given" that X < 9. Which is also X > 8 = .64437.

Comment: Oh wait. X = 8! That would be .18517

Answer (score 2):

Now that the OP has figured it out, I'll answer the question in full:

> Calculate P[ X > 7|X < 9 ]

$P(A|B) = P(AB)/P(B),\quad \text{so}$

\begin{eqnarray}
(X>7|X<9) &=& \frac{P(7<X<9)}{P(X<9)} \\
&=& \frac{P(X=8)}{P(X\leq 8)}\quad\quad^\text{(I'd normally stop there, but I want to use your figures from your tables)}\\
&=&\frac{[P(X \leq 8) - P(X\leq 7)]}{P(X \leq 8)}\\
&=&1 - \frac{P(X\leq 7)}{P(X \leq 8)}\\
& =&  1-  \frac{.45920}{.64437} = 0.28737\\
\end{eqnarray}